# I have got an error when installing appium

Tags: appium, ubuntu

I am working with appium and installed idea intellij, android sdk, appium. when I run uiautomatorviewer

```
naveen@naveen-Inspiron-3542:~/Music/android-sdk-linux/tools$ uiautomatorviewer 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale$Builder.build()Lcom/ibm/icu/util/ULocale;
        at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.addULocale(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:206)
        at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.getLocales(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:140)
        at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.getAvailableLocales(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:53)
        at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.util.CurrencyNameProviderICU.getAvailableLocales(CurrencyNameProviderICU.java:39)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter$CurrencyNameProviderDelegate.addImpl(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:485)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter$CurrencyNameProviderDelegate.addImpl(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:479)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:97)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:74)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter.findInstalledProvider(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:74)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.AuxLocaleProviderAdapter.getLocaleServiceProvider(AuxLocaleProviderAdapter.java:70)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.<init>(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:133)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getPool(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:111)
        at java.util.Currency.getSymbol(Currency.java:506)
        at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:648)
        at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:113)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85)
        at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:180)
        at java.util.Formatter.getZero(Formatter.java:2283)
        at java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1892)
        at java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1914)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
        at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.checkAdbVersion(AndroidDebugBridge.java:583)
        at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.<init>(AndroidDebugBridge.java:559)
        at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge(AndroidDebugBridge.java:319)
        at com.android.uiautomator.DebugBridge.init(DebugBridge.java:68)
        at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:71)


 java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Please help me to resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your SDK.
And also try https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/363